# Nestjs custom validation pipe Undefined

Tags: javascript, pipe, nestjs

I got a problem in my custom validation pipe
I'm trying to verify if the id passed exist in an other table.

[image]

it telling me that it can not read property of undefined but I console log the id and you can see that its correcly console above the error message.

I've also check if my findOne works in a route and its doing find

```html
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  ValidatorConstraint,
  ValidatorConstraintInterface,
} from 'class-validator';
import { ExerciceRepository } from 'src/Infrastructure/repository/exercice.repository';

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'ExerciceExists', async: true })
@Injectable()
export class ExerciceExistRule implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  constructor(private exerciceRepository: ExerciceRepository) {}

  async validate(value: string): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log(value);

    try {
      const data = await this.exerciceRepository.findOne(value);
      console.log(data);
      if (data) return true;
      else return false;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);

      return false;
    }
  }
  defaultMessage(): string {
    return 'Exercice doesnt exist';
  }
}
```

Thank you for your repplies

Comment: It not telling you, that `value` is undefined, but `exerciseRepository` is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution I had to put UseContainer in the main.ts.
It will allow class-validator to use NESTJS dependency injection container.

`useContainer(app.select(AppModule), { fallbackOnErrors: true });`

However i don't know if it's the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the error message wrong. It is not telling, that `value` or `findOne` is undefined, but the object from which it is trying to read the property of: `exerciceRepository`.

This indicates, that you did not register your `ExerciceRepository` correctly.
Verify, that it has the `@Injectable()` attribute and that it is registered as a  provider in the Nest IoC container in your `app.module.ts`:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [/*...*/],
  providers: [ExerciseRepository],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I don't understand why?  My repository has the @Injectable attribute and he his provide in my module.
I use this repository in a service and its working find but not in the pipe